# Quartz -> Start process at 06:30 and repeat every 2 minutes until 21:00

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Is it possible to define ONE cron expression that will trigger a process at 06:30 and repeat it every 2 minutes until 21:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to do that with a single cron expression (i.e. a single CronTrigger). But you can maybe use the DailyTimeIntervalTrigger with the following parameters to achive your goal. This is exactly the type of schedule the DailyTimeIntervalTrigger is meant to be used for.

[image]